# Headless UI open one of the Disclosure's on init

Tags: tailwind-css, headless, tailwind-ui, headless-ui

I'm having trouble opening one of the 2 Disclosure.

Attached below is what trying to achieve this and when I add the `static` prop it keeps it open indefinitely.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for here. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just Pass the defaultOpen props to Disclosure.
`<Disclosure defaultOpen>`